# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi(n)}{e^n}\sin ns$ on an horizontal closed strip

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, chebyshev-function

Let $\psi(x)=\sum_{k\leq x}\Lambda(k)$ the **Second Chebyshev function**, and $\epsilon>0$. I would like to ask

> **Question.** Can you prove or disprove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi(n)}{e^n}\sin ns$$
>   converges uniformly on each strip $ \left\{ s\in\mathbb{C}: \left| \Im s \right|\leq 1-\epsilon \right\} $.

Let a $s=x+iy$ in such strip, from $-(1-\epsilon)\leq y\leq 1+\epsilon$,  then $y\leq 1+\epsilon$ and $-(1-\epsilon)\leq y$ thus $-y\leq1-\epsilon$ and $y\leq 1+\epsilon$ and following the computations one can write $$ \left| \frac{\psi(n)e^{-n}}{2i} \right|\cdot \left| e^{in(x+iy)}-e^{-in(x+iy)} \right|\leq \frac{\psi(n)e^{-n}}{2}  \left(  \left| e^{inx} \right| \left| e^{-ny} \right| + \left| e^{-inx} \right|  \left| e^{ny}\right|   \right)  $$
thus $$ \left|\frac{\psi(n)\sin nz}{e^{n}} \right| \leq \frac{\psi(n)}{2e^n}(e^{n(1-\epsilon)}+e^{n(1-\epsilon)})=\frac{\psi(n)}{e^{n\epsilon}}.$$

> **Claim.** And since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{e^{\epsilon n}}$ is summable for each $\epsilon>0$ , the **Weierstrass theorem** implies our that the previous series converges uniformly on the cited closed strip.

Notice that I don't write ..*since* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi(n)}{e^{\epsilon n}}$ *is summable*..., since I believe that it is sufficient study those series in my **Claim.**

**I don't know if previous claim is right, and I don't understand/remember why from the summability as geometric series of the negative exponential one has the statement about the uniformly  for the first series.**

I know these computations, that **Prime Number theorem** can be written as equivalence with $\psi(n)=n+o(n)$ as $n\to\infty$. That for a real variable $x>0$ one has $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{nx}}=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}-1$ uniformly convergent on compact subset of $(0,\infty)$ by Weierstrass, thus one can derive term by term to get $$-\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d}{dx}e^{-nx}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-nx}$$ uniformly convergent on compact subset of $(0,\infty)$ by Weierstrass (**but I don't understand what means the summability versus the uniformly convergence of the series**).

**Many thanks.**

Comment: I've studied this theory about 2003, and I am inspired in this exercise in [this Ejercicio 1 in spanish from the Universidad Autónoma de Madrid](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/dragan/licenc/varcomI-0708-prob-res.pdf), now I don't remember what's means summability and its relationship with the uniformly convergence.

Comment: After there is an answer I will delete the comments useless or that are no related with the post. I've tried to study also the following for the same strip (I think through comparisons and similarities) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)e^{-n}\cos ns,$$ solved, but the following are open $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma(n)e^{-n}\cos ns$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\psi(n)}\cos ns$ or $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-n}e^{\frac{2\pi iks}{n}},$$ where the functions are the well-known arithmetic functions.